# Is there a way to only show sticky entries?

Tags: entries

Currently using Playa on a site to allow the client to pick what news entries show up on the homepage as they don't always want to show the newest entry, they want to show the most important. But it's a small nag to have them create a news post then have to open another "Home" entry to drag and drop news items. I was thinking it might be easier for them to set news articles as Sticky when they are creating them, then only display the sticky entries on the homepage. if I just set sticky="yes" this would show sticky entries on top, but might not show all sticky entries if the limit=3 and 4 sticky entries are set. Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done that sort of thing using a status and limiting the items displayed on the home page to just those with that status.  And you can, as of 2.5.4, order by status, putting them up first if you so choose, mirroring sticky functionality, on your inside page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a {if sticky == 'y'} content {/if} conditional in your entries loop to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "push" entries to the home page based on data in the entry, I'd recommend that you use either a special "home page" category or a new field. Then you can use the exp:channel:entries tag limited by either a specific category_id or a search term, respectively.

The special category option is nice because you can filter by category in the control panel. So, it's easy then to find the current home page entries, for editing (e.g., for removing them from the home page category).

Using a special status for the entries is pretty similar to using a special category. I don't like to use special statuses for this because I try to limit my use of statuses only close and open, and have them mean only "off" and "on" (since EE makes them mean that, by default).

With the way you're currently using Playa, (I assume) you're "pulling" entries into the home page entry. Another good way to pull entries into a template is with [Low Reorder](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-reorder) using its own [Entries Tag](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-reorder/docs/tags#entries-tag). It has a handy drag-n-drop interface in the control panel.