# How to feature entries on homepage

Tags: channel-entries

I have several channels of content and wish to flag selected entries to display on a section in the homepage. I know Joomla has this built into each article, and wondered how I would achieve this with EE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a channel field that marks the entry as being eligible for "featured" (a simple Yes/No dropdown should do). Then in your template, simply grab the entries with a channel entries tag that have the featured field set to Yes. You can also use additional parameters such as orderby="random" and placing limits to how many items get returned (and set dynamic="no" as well).

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use the status parameter on the channel entries tag. If you were to add a status of featured you could then do something along the lines of

```
{exp:channen:entries channel="channrl1|channel2" status="featured"}
```

On the homepage. You would just need to make sure that you declare both open and featured on any entry tags you wanted both types to appear in because the entry tag only displays open by default.

```
{exp:channen:entries channel="channel1" status="open|featured"}
```

Depending on the amount of entires that you have in your EE install using the search parameter (as some of the other commenters have suggested) on the channel entries tag can cause a performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can make entries [sticky](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/publish.html#make-entry-sticky) to make the stick on top.

And follow [answers in this thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12761/is-there-a-way-to-only-show-sticky-entries) to display only sticky entries on your homepage (or whereever)

While this is native, I would personally just add a custom checkbox field 'display_on_homepage' and fetch entries with

> {exp:channel:entries search:display_on_homepage="y"}

Comment: Hi Yuri, a question: if you're dealing with multiple channels, would the checkbox field have to have an individual name for each channel (if each channel has its own fields)?

Comment: Well, I usually follow approach "one fieldset for all channel" and hide the fields I don't need using Publosh Layouts. But in case you have multiple fieldsets, the approach I desribed in my answer will probably not work

Comment: Ah, got it! Thanks for the clarification! I've heard of people doing one fieldset, but I've never done that myself.